# Monitor Situation In Detail

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*in detail*".  Most dictionary definition give example usages of "*in detail*" like these:

> He explained the theory **in detail**.
>   They discussed the matter **in detail**.
>   They talked about the issues **in detail**.

, where the contexts appear to be production of information.

But, then there is this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Militia_occupation_of_the_Malheur_National_Wildlife_Refuge#Response_of_authorities):

> U.S. Senator Ron Wyden of Oregon said that he had been briefed by the special agent in charge of the Portland FBI field office and said that federal, state, and local law enforcement were **monitoring the situation in detail**.

"*Monitoring a situation*" is not quite the same type of context as "*explain the theory*" or "*discuss a matter*" or "*talk about issues*".  So, is the usage in the wikipedia article wrong?

Answer (score 6):

To explain something **in detail** is to talk about the **finer points** of an idea.

To monitor something **in detail** has essentially the same meaning, to keep track of the **smallest items or events**.  Wikipedia is not wrong.

Remember, the devil's **in the details**!